# How to test Eclipse plugins?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, testing, plugins

What would be the best means/tools for testing an Eclipse plugin? Are there some tools for testing the GUI features of an application created with Eclipse plugins?

Comment: I meant automated tests - sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the possibilities, I have opted for using Jubula for testing the GUI part:

[Eclipse Jubula Project](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/)

It's a good tool for creating tests specific for an RCP application. Moreover, it's not code based and it allows the creation of tests from a user point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to keep GUI tests to a minimum since they are slow to run and takes time to create. If your code is well structured in a Model-view-controller pattern then the GUI specific code should be minimal.

Thats the theory in a perfect world atleast. Until we get there, I prefer to use [SWTbot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/)

Comment: +1. Though the development of SWTBot is not so active, but it's enough to automatically test GUI based on Eclipse 3.x. Not sure whether it works on 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse [Jubula](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/) is a very nice tool for GUI based testing for Eclipse plugins. It provides automated functional GUI testing for various types of applications. It is aimed at teams who want their automated tests to be written by test experts from the user perspective, without requiring any coding effort. Jubula tests incorporate best practices from software development to ensure long-term maintainability of the automated tests.

1. It'll be useful to work with Jenkins as your CI build system.
2. You can connect to a real database as your wish for test result storage purposes.
3. You can save screenshots taken by Jubula upon test failures directly in the test report

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to take a look at [RCP Testing Tool](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/). This tool lets you to develop dozens of UI tests per day per engineer, and do not have stability and incorrect-recording problems. It's designed specially and only to test Eclipse-based apps. It is official Eclipse project and it's free.